# difference between header files “<stdio.h>” and “<stdlib.h>”

Tags: c, header, header-files, stdio

What’s the difference between the header files “`<stdio.h>`” and “`<stdlib.h>`” in C programming?

Comment: They have different library functions declared in them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One has set of function declarations, constants, macros and type definitions, the other has a ***different*** set of function declarations, constants, macros and type definitions. You are able to open the file with a simple text editor if you want to see the contents.

---

`stdio` stands for standard input/output, its contents are usually but not exclusively related to input output operations, either with hardware or physical devices or with files supported by the system. A list of functions declarations, macros and type definitions available [can be found here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/):

**Functions:**

- **Operations on files:**

  - remove - Remove file
  - rename - Rename file
  - tmpfile - Open a temporary file
  - tmpnam - Generate temporary filename
- **File access:**

  - fclose - Close file
  - fflush - Flush stream
  - fopen - Open file
  - freopen - Reopen stream with different file or mode
  - setbuf - Set stream buffer
  - setvbuf - Change stream buffering
- **Formatted input/output:**

  - fprintf - Write formatted data to stream
  - fscanf - Read formatted data from stream
  - printf - Print formatted data to stdout
  - scanf - Read formatted data from stdin
  - snprintf - Write formatted output to sized buffer
  - sprintf - Write formatted data to string
  - sscanf - Read formatted data from string
  - vfprintf - Write formatted data from variable argument list to stream
  - vfscanf - Read formatted data from stream into variable argument list
  - vprintf - Print formatted data from variable argument list to stdout
  - vscanf - Read formatted data into variable argument list
  - vsnprintf - Write formatted data from variable argument list to sized buffer
  - vsprintf - Write formatted data from variable argument list to string
  - vsscanf - Read formatted data from string into variable argument list
- **Character input/output:**

  - fgetc - Get character from stream
  - fgets - Get string from stream
  - fputc - Write character to stream
  - fputs - Write string to stream
  - getc - Get character from stream
  - getchar - Get character from stdin
  - gets - Get string from stdin
  - putc - Write character to stream
  - putchar - Write character to stdout
  - puts - Write string to stdout
  - ungetc - Unget character from stream
- **Direct input/output:**

  - fread - Read block of data from stream
  - fwrite - Write block of data to stream
- **File positioning:**

  - fgetpos - Get current position in stream
  - fseek - Reposition stream position indicator
  - fsetpos - Set position indicator of stream
  - ftell - Get current position in stream
  - rewind - Set position of stream to the beginning
- **Error-handling:**

  - clearerr - Clear error indicators
  - feof - Check end-of-file indicator
  - ferror - Check error indicator
  - perror - Print error message

**Macros:**

- BUFSIZ - Buffer size
- EOF - End-of-File
- FILENAME_MAX - Maximum length of file names
- FOPEN_MAX - Potential limit of simultaneous open streams
- L_tmpnam - Minimum length for temporary file name
- NULL - Null pointer (macro )
- TMP_MAX - Number of temporary files
- Additionally: _IOFBF, _IOLBF, _IONBF (used with setvbuf)
  and SEEK_CUR, SEEK_END and SEEK_SET (used with fseek).

**Types:**

- FILE - Object containing information to control a stream
- fpos_t - Object containing information to specify a position within a file
- size_t - Unsigned integral type

---

`stdlib` stands for standard library and it has general purpose functions, including dynamic memory management, random number generation, communication, arithmetics, searching, sorting and converting, etc. A list of functions declarations, macros and type definitions available [can be found here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/):

**Functions**

- **String conversion**

  - atof - Convert string to double
  - atoi - Convert string to integer
  - atol - Convert string to long integer
  - atoll - Convert string to long long integer
  - strtod - Convert string to double
  - strtof - Convert string to float
  - strtol - Convert string to long integer
  - strtold - Convert string to long double
  - strtoll - Convert string to long long integer
  - strtoul - Convert string to unsigned long integer
  - strtoull - Convert string to unsigned long long integer
- **Pseudo-random sequence generation**

  - rand - Generate random number
  - srand - Initialize random number generator
- **Dynamic memory management**

  - calloc - Allocate and zero-initialize array
  - free - Deallocate memory block
  - malloc - Allocate memory block
  - realloc - Reallocate memory block
- **Environment**

  - abort - Abort current process
  - atexit - Set function to be executed on exit
  - at_quick_exit - Set function to be executed on quick exit
  - exit - Terminate calling process
  - getenv - Get environment string
  - quick_exit - Terminate calling process quick
  - system - Execute system command
  - _Exit - Terminate calling process
- **Searching and sorting**

  - bsearch - Binary search in array
  - qsort - Sort elements of array
- **Integer arithmetics**

  - abs - Absolute value
  - div - Integral division
  - labs - Absolute value
  - ldiv - Integral division
  - llabs - Absolute value
  - lldiv - Integral division
- **Multibyte characters**

  - mblen - Get length of multibyte character
  - mbtowc - Convert multibyte sequence to wide character
  - wctomb - Convert wide character to multibyte sequence
- **Multibyte strings**

  - mbstowcs - Convert multibyte string to wide-character string
  - wcstombs - Convert wide-character string to multibyte string

**Macro constants**

- EXIT_FAILURE - Failure termination code
- EXIT_SUCCESS - Success termination code
- MB_CUR_MAX - Maximum size of multibyte characters
- NULL - Null pointer
- RAND_MAX - Maximum value returned by rand

**Types**

- div_t - Structure returned by div
- ldiv_t - Structure returned by ldiv
- lldiv_t - Structure returned by lldiv
- size_t - Unsigned integral type

Answer (score 2):

One easy way to differentiate these two header files is that “<stdio.h>” contains declaration of printf() and scanf() while “<stdlib.h>” contains declaration of malloc() and free(). In that sense, the main difference in these two header files can considered that, while “<stdio.h>” contains header information for ‘File related Input/Output’ functions, “<stdlib.h>” contains header information for ‘Memory Allocation/Freeing’ functions.

Comment: While `<stdlib.h.` _does_ declare the memory management functions, it also declares a lot of others.  The main sections of [§7.22 General utilities `<stdlib.h>`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22) are: §7.22.1 Numeric conversion functions,
§7.22.2 Pseudo-random sequence generation functions,
§7.22.3 Memory management functions,
§7.22.4 Communication with the environment,
§7.22.5 Searching and sorting utilities,
§7.22.6 Integer arithmetic functions,
§7.22.7 Multibyte/wide character conversion functions,
§7.22.8 Multibyte/wide string conversion functions.

Answer (score 2):

They have different contents.

The C standard library is divided up into several major areas, each with a separate header file.

`stdio.h` (standard I/O) contains macro definitions, type definitions, and function declarations for routines dealing with text and binary I/O (`printf`, `scanf`, `fopen`, `getchar`, etc.).

`stdlib.h` (standard library) contains macro definitions, type definitions, and function declarations for routines dealing with memory management, text-to-numeric conversions, random numbers, etc. (`malloc`, `calloc`, `strtol`, `rand`, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

***stdio.h***

C library to perform ***Input/Output*** operations
Input and Output operations can also be performed in C++ using the C Standard Input and Output Library (cstdio, known as studio. h in the C language). This library uses streams to operate with physical devices such as keyboards, printers, terminals, or any other type of files supported by the system. Streams are an abstraction to interact with these uniformly; All streams have similar properties independently of the physical media's individual characteristics.

Streams are handled in the cstdio library as pointers to FILE objects. A pointer to a FILE object uniquely identifies a stream, and is used as a parameter in the operations involving that stream.

There also exist three standard streams: stdin, stdout and stderr, which are automatically created and opened for all programs using the library.

***stdlib.h***

The <stdlib.h> library (for standard library) offers functions to answer various problems. First of all, this library will allow you to manage memory dynamically, by allocating or freeing memory in the heap. It will also allow you to be able to interact with the operating system on which the program is running. This library also offers many other utility functions for converting between data types, algorithms (sorting, dichotomous search, generation of pseudo-random numbers, etc) and some other possibilities.